# Esiste una lista delle parole più comuni con la pronuncia milanese?

Tags: regional, pronunciation

Mettiamola così: sto cercando di imparare la pronuncia milanese. La miglior fonte che ho trovato è questo video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Arq9qNRoLw

Il video spiega le regole, quindi possiamo dire che le regole le conosco. Quello che non so però è quando l'apertura/ la chiusura del suono cambia (rispetto all'italiano standard ossia la pronuncia descritta al Wiktionary inglese) quando non c'è una regola.

Il video spiega per esempio che a Milano si dice "quèsto" e "cósto" (e una regola per queste parole non esiste). Dove posso trovare una lista di esempi isolati più completa? Online o offline. Sarebbe perfetto se spiegasse la pronuncia delle parole più comuni e non solo quelle che piacciano all'autore.

Comment: Non ho una lista completa, ma vivendo a Milano ti posso dire quelle che mi vengono in mente sul momento... forchètta, sédia, tònno, ténda, biciclètta, béne, magliètta, gònna, bigliètto, bècco...